# Selenium Node.js: How to click the same button on several overlapping elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I am working with Selenium and have an issue by closing several HTML Elements, which have the same "close" button. These elements are overlapping each other. My idea was to loop through them and close one by one, but it seems not to work.

First I get all "close" buttons:

```
let by = By.className("jsPanel-btn jsPanel-btn-close jsPanel-btn-md");
let panelsCloseBtns = await this.getElements(by); //custom func to get close button by xpath
```

It returns array of Selenium Elements.

Then I have tried 3 approaches, but it works only with the first element:

Using actions:

```
// Close buttons one by one
for (let i=0; panelsCloseBtns.length; i++) {
    if (i === panelsCloseBtns.length) break;
    try{
        await this.driver.actions().mouseMove(panelsCloseBtns[i]).click().perform();
    }catch(ElementClickInterceptedError) {
        await this.driver.actions().mouseMove(panelsCloseBtns[i]).click().perform();
    }
}
```

It clicks the first element and then I get the error of ElementClickInterceptedError

Using executeScript

```
for (let i=0; panelsCloseBtns.length; i++) {
    if (i === panelsCloseBtns.length) break;
    await this.driver.executeScript(`arguments[${i}].click();`, panelsCloseBtns[i]);
}
```

The same result as by actions

The third is just click the button

```
for (let i=0; panelsCloseBtns.length; i++) {
    if (i === panelsCloseBtns.length) break;
    panelsCloseBtns[i].click();
}
```

The same result as by actions

I am not sure, how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
await this.driver.executeScript(`arguments[${i}].click();`, panelsCloseBtns[i]);
```

it should always be arguments[0] because you're only passing one argument.

You're clicking all of them at the same time though, which might cause problems